# Creating a list from ranked

Tags: vba, excel

I need help writing a loop to find the first ranked team in each conference and add them to a different worksheet.

For instance

```
Team - Conference - Rank
A - WEST - 1 
B - WEST - 2
C - EAST - 3
D - EAST -4
E - NORTH - 5
```

Conference winners A, C, and E should be selected even though Team B and D's Ranks are higher. I need to design a loop to filter through 250 teams and 10 Conferences.

Comment: Thanks for the idea and help!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually, copying the data, sorting by (conference, rank) then remove duplicates on conference. If there's a reason to do it with VBA, this is the equivalent:

```
Sub GetFirstByConf()
    With Worksheets.Add
        .name = "FirstTeamByConf"
        Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Copy .Range("A1")
        .UsedRange.Sort key1:=.Columns("B"), key2:=.Columns("C"), header:=xlYes
        .UsedRange.RemoveDuplicates 2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks I tried to upvote but I don't have enough reputation to upvote yet

Comment: @Wombat you dont have to upvote, you can just *accept* the answer by clicking the gray checkmark on the topleft of the answer (below the triangles) thanks :)